# Python/Functional noob, convert unreadable Java recursion to Python

Tags: java, python, recursion, functional-programming

I am trying to dust off some core coding skills but brain is poisoned with too much Java :( . I am starting off with recursion and here is a simple piece of code.

```
static ArrayList<String> createSentences(ArrayList<String[]> listsOfWords, int listIdx) {
    if (listIdx == listsOfWords.size())
        return null;

    String[] currListOfWords = listsOfWords.get(listIdx);
    ArrayList<String> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String word : currListOfWords) {
        ArrayList<String> fragments = createSentences(listsOfWords, listIdx + 1);
        if (fragments != null) {
            for (String fragment : fragments) {
                sentences.add(word + " " + fragment);
            }
        } else {
            sentences.add(word);
        }
    }

    return sentences;
}
```

What this code is doing is taking an input in the form...

```
{
 {"tom","dick","harry"},
 {"was","is"}
 {"noob","average","expert"}
}
```

And convert it to the following...

```
"tom was noob"
"tom was average"
"tom was expert"
"dick was noob"
"dick was average"
"dick was expert"
```

... and so on

This is simply a recursion of the form f(n+1) = L(n) + f(n) ?

My guess is there is a better way to represent this in Python (OR other Functional languages)

Can anybody please point me in the right direction here as to

1. Can this code be made more readable using Python ? My eyes bleed
   looking at the code sample above.
2. Is there another language I should consider for practicing recursion ? Haskell maybe ?

### Regards,

G

Comment: In python it can be done in one line `print("\n".join(" ".join(tup) for tup in itertools.product(*l)))`

Comment: It's not the language that will lead to a more elegant solution but rather the creativity and design skills of the programmer. Only a *"bad workman quarrels with his tools."*

Comment: I.K. can you possibly provide an insightful example ?

Comment: As to "Haskell for practicing recursion": Yes, that would definitely help. There is basically no alternative to recursion in Haskell (modulo "recursion hidden behind a library").

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way in python would be to use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
print("\n".join(" ".join(tup) for tup in itertools.product(*l)))
```

To do it recursively you can use a list comprehension:

```
def rec_prod(l):
    if not l:
        return [[]]
    else:
        return [[name] + prod for name in l[0] for prod in rec_prod(l[1:])]
print("\n".join(" ".join(tup) for tup in rec_prod(l)))


tom was noob 
tom was average 
tom was expert 
tom is noob 
tom is average 
tom is expert 
dick was noob 
dick was average 
dick was expert 
dick is noob 
dick is average 
dick is expert 
harry was noob 
harry was average 
harry was expert 
harry is noob 
harry is average 
harry is expert
```

Which is equivalent to nested for loops:

```
for name in l[0]:
    for i in l[1]:
        for w in l[2:]:
            print(name,i,w)
```

Comment: Thanks @Padraic Cunningham